# Form Validation ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Think i am overlooking the issue, when i click submit nothing comes up but when i enter data in one of the text boxes and not all over them i get an error message in the script.

What would i need to add or change so that i get the message when the do not enter data in any of the boxes

```
    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        if (jobsdate.Text == "" && firstjob.Text == "" && firstbudgetjob.Text == "" && secondjob.Text == "" && thirdjob.Text == "" && nightwork.Text == "" && otherwork.Text == "")
        {
            conform.Text = "Please Enter Data";
            return;
        }            
        else
        {
            execution(submittime.Text, jobsdate.Text, firstjob.Text, firstbudgetjob.Text, secondjob.Text, thirdjob.Text, nightwork.Text, otherwork.Text, totaljobs.Text, overbudget.Text);
            conform.Visible = true;
            submittime.Text = "";
            jobsdate.Text = "";
            firstjob.Text = "";
            firstbudgetjob.Text = "";
            secondjob.Text = "";
            thirdjob.Text = "";
            nightwork.Text = "";
            otherwork.Text = "";
            totaljobs.Text = "";
            overbudget.Text = "";                                    
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using Validator objects for form validation in ASP.net.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7kh55542(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7kh55542%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
if (jobsdate.Text == "" && firstjob.Text == "" && 
    firstbudgetjob.Text == "" && secondjob.Text == "" && 
     thirdjob.Text == "" && nightwork.Text == "" && otherwork.Text == "")
```

to be resolved as true and enter the if block need to have all textboxes empty. 
If you want to emit the warning when just one textbox is empty you need to use the || (OR operator)
together with [string.IsNullOrWitheSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jobsdate.Text) || 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstjob.Text) || 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstbudgetjob.Text) || 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secondjob.Text) || 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thirdjob.Text) || 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nightwork.Text) || 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(otherwork.Text))
{
   conform.Text = "Please Enter Data";
    return;
}
else
{
    .....
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but now i dont get any message come up using your WAY

Comment: Do you want the message ("Please Enter Data") when you have just one textbox empty? or only if ALL textboxes are empty?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, how i want it is if they click on submit with out entering anything they get the message or if they just enter data in to one text box and leave the rest of the boxes they get the message

Comment: The the || (OR operator) should be correct unless the textbox are not really emtpy. In that case you could use IsNullOrWhiteSpace

Comment: No everything was empty, thats why i was scratching my head over it

Comment: Also note that your execution method requires 10 parameters, but the if checks only on 7 of them

Comment: Right using the other way i get nothing using || and i the the message using & but only when data is entered in to one of the boxes

Answer (score 0):

```
if (jobsdate.Text.Replace(" ","") == "" && firstjob.Text.Replace(" ","") == "" && firstbudgetjob.Text.Replace(" ","") == "" && secondjob.Text.Replace(" ","") == "" && thirdjob.Text.Replace(" ","") == "" && nightwork.Text.Replace(" ","") == "" && otherwork.Text.Replace(" ","") == "")

{
   conform.Text = "Please Enter Data";
   return;
}
```

Not sure if this works for you.

But this works for me if the user left all text box empty.

Just replace && with || if you want message appear when user left a single textbox empty

Comment: submittime.Text = ""; this displays the time and date could this be the issue because when the user clicks submit this info is the only info which is displayed